# Unwanted behaviour with threaded kivy app: Frame drops when second thread is running, even when there is no exchange of data between threads

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, kivy, python-multithreading

I am a musician and had the idea to program a signal generator (gates, envelopes, control signals) for my modular synth. With a digital to analog converter voltages are being used to control the synth.

Now for the GUI I chose kivy, since its cross platform (so I can run it on a tablet or my raspberry pi) and supports touch screen. Also, my programming skills are not top-notch, but I think I have a pretty good grasp on Python.

Since it's a musical application, the output needs to be generated at a certain sample rate (around 8000 samples/second or higher would be nice). Now the kivy app itself runs at 30 fps, so logically I chose to thread the signal-computing part of the program. The GUI is used to change the parameters of the signal generation.

Now, I have run into the problem that the kivy frame rate drop, when the computational thread is started. I have done some digging into threaded kivy programs and their quirks. But most problems come from the data exchange between the threads. Now I have noticed, that the frame drops occur even when there is no exchange between the two threads (nothing but the threading.Event to stop the second thread).

My wish is to use this program to play sets live, so a smooth GUI is essential to me and I just can't figure out, why the kivy GUI is influenced by the other thread, even when nothing is exchanged.

I know, this is a big read, but I am at boundary of my programming knowledge here, so I am in search of more competent people than me.

Here is a Python script which boils the problem down to its roots: A button to start and stop the signal computing thread (which doesn't compute anything here, just clocks the sample rate) and a button which when clicked can be dragged around (to visualize the problem). Now, with the second thread not running, the dragging is smooth (in my program the GUI is smooth in this state). As soon as the second thread is started the GUI (in this case the button movement) gets rough and lags quite bad (even at low sample rates).

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.floatlayout import FloatLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.behaviors import DragBehavior
import threading
from time import perf_counter



class ThreadingApp(App):

    stop_compute_thread = threading.Event()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(ThreadingApp, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.sample_rate = 8000
        self.compute_thread_run = False

    def on_stop(self):
        # stop secondary thread when app is closed
        self.stop_compute_thread.set()

    def build(self):
        layout = FloatLayout()
        ThreadButton = Button(text="Start/Stop Compute Thread", size_hint=(.3, .15), pos_hint={"right": 1, "top":1})
        ThreadButton.bind(on_release=lambda x: self.thread_start_stop())
        layout.add_widget(ThreadButton)
        DragButton = DraggableButton(text="Dragable Button", size_hint=(None, None), size=(250, 150))
        layout.add_widget(DragButton)
        return layout

    def thread_start_stop(self):
        # start or stop the secondary thread depending if its running or not
        if self.compute_thread_run:
            self.stop_compute_thread.set()
        else:
            threading.Thread(target=self.compute_thread).start()

    def compute_thread(self):
        # contains the infinite loop for secondary thread, perf counters to monitor its behaviour (and clock the sample rate)
        print("Starting secondary compute thread.")
        self.compute_thread_run = True
        iteration = 0
        iteration_time = 1 / self.sample_rate
        thread_start = perf_counter()

        while True:
            iter_start = perf_counter()
            if self.stop_compute_thread.is_set():
                thread_stop = perf_counter()
                self.compute_thread_run = False
                self.stop_compute_thread.clear()
                print("Computed ", iteration, " iterations in ", thread_stop - thread_start, " seconds.")
                return
            self.compute_signal()
            while perf_counter() < iter_start + iteration_time:
                # wait until the time to compute one sample has elapsed
                # is this the culprit?
                pass
            iteration += 1

    def compute_signal(self):
        # place holder, here the actual computation and output of the signal takes place
        # shared variables between threads are handles with queues
        pass


class DraggableButton(DragBehavior, Button):
    def on_touch_move(self, touch):
        if self.collide_point(*touch.pos):
            self.center = touch.pos
            return True
        return super(DraggableButton, self).on_touch_move(touch)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    ThreadingApp().run()
```

Regards,

Lupo

Comment: You may want to consider multiprocessing in place of threads. See this [GIL documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.10/c-api/init.html?highlight=gil#thread-state-and-the-global-interpreter-lock)

Comment: So would I need to run the Kivy app in one process and the signal computation in the other? If not, how would you apply multiprocessing to this problem?

Comment: When you run your App, it runs in its own process. Then you can create additional processes using the capabilities in [concurrent execution](https://docs.python.org/3.10/library/concurrency.html). You can use `Process`, `SubProcess`, or a `Process Pool`. There are also several ways to pass information between the processes. You would have to choose based on your specific needs.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for your help. I did some more digging and Kivy and multiprocessing should be avoided. Turns out, that I chose the wrong framework to code my GUI entirely. PyQt has good threading capabilities without locking the GUI up. I programmed an equivalent to the script above and it works perfectly. Well, I guess my last weeks of GUI coding is down the drain.